# Use Excel to query Sybase database

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database

Excel offers the ability to connect to external data sources. I am told I can connect to a Sybase database to import some data into excel from a query.

How do I do this? I have the following:

- Query
- Server
- Port
- Database
- Username
- Password

I know this can be done with VBA also, but I'd prefer to do it with the interface so I can teach others.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Take that query, server, etc info and apply it to the process: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx (first result from googling: excel external database)

Comment: @Wutnaut I don't know what goes in the "DataSource" and "initialCatalog" sections

Comment: "What is a data source? A data source is a stored set of information that allows Excel and Microsoft Query to connect to an external database. When you use Microsoft Query to set up a data source, you give the data source a name, and then supply the name and the location of the database or server, the type of database, and your logon and password information. The information also includes the name of an OBDC driver or a data source driver, which is a program that makes connections to a specific type of database." You set up the DataSource.

Comment: I'm not sure about 'initialCatalog', my guess is they mean "root directory". Try leaving blank or "."

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is I get to a screen which has a "DataSource" textbox on it. Clearly this needs to contain the server and port, but what is the format?